# OpenID and Wordpress user account creation

Tags: wordpress, openid

Currently, the admin in wordpress can create user accounts. How can the admin associate an OpenID with the account it creates?

Answer (score 0):

Use [XRDS-Simple](http://hueniverse.com/misc/xrds-simple/)

- [Description](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/)
- [Installation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/installation/)
- [Download](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/openid.3.3.3.zip)

Here are articles that will guide you step by step integration and usage:

- [WordPress OpenID Plugin](http://verselogic.net/projects/wordpress/wordpress-openid-plugin/)
- [Settings » OpenID](http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/openid/)

Comment: I have installed the OpenID plugin. What I don't know is how I use this XRDS-Simple to enable the admin to create a whitelist of OpenIDs that are allowed to log in and contribute to the wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0):

Link fixes needed.

The "WordPress OpenID Plugin" link for "step by step integration and usage" above gets a "404 Not Found" error when it goes to:

verselogicDOTnet SLASH projects SLASH wordpress SLASH wordpress-openid-plugin SLASH

the Wordpress OpenID plugin page also has a how-to wiki which does not resolve properly

ON:  wordpressDOTorg SLASH extend SLASH plugins SLASH openid SLASH

Developer Documentation Link is also Dead:

"Developer documention, which includes all of the public methods and hooks for integrating with and extending the plugin, can be found 'here'."

'here' link is bad (it is redirected) -- this is dead link on that page:

wiki DOT diso-projectDOTorg SLASH wordpress-openid-api

Sorry, I don't see a way to submit correction requests here.